# ObRegisterCallbacks: MSDN documentation/sample code discrepency

Tags: windows, winapi, kernel, driver

There are some discrepancies relating to ObRegsterCallbacks in the documentation and sample code that contradict one another.  I'm hoping someone from Microsoft reads this board and can provide a straight answer.

First, here is some background:

- Kernel Data and Filtering Support For Vista SP1 page 12

  "The OB callback is always made in the context of the originating process & thread."
- MSDN documentation on OB_PRE_OPERATION_CALLBACK

  "This routine is called at PASSIVE_LEVEL in an arbitrary thread context with normal kernel APCs disabled."
- ObCallback Callback Registration Driver sample code in the WDK

  Uses PsGetCurrentXXX routines to compare against the target object.

It seems the utility of these callbacks is pretty limited if you can't accurately determine the originating process/thread but per the current documentation that seems to be the case.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you got your answer on OSR Online, though it would be helpful for other users if you could notify them of the answer you got [there](http://www.osronline.com/showThread.CFM?link=255898):

> The callbacks are invoked in the context of the thread that initiates the handle 
>   operation in question. The documentation could be more precise on this point.
>   - S (Msft)